# Password Post not working Reactjs with Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to send a name and a password to a Nodejs server (with Expressjs) from a Reactjs front end. When I send the name and password, only the name is sent. Here is my Reactjs code :

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
    console.log(this.state.signInPassword);
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: this.state.signinName,
            password: this.state.signinPassword
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(user => {
        if(user.id){
            this.props.loadUser(user);
            this.props.onRouteChange('home');
        }
    })
}
```

This function triggers correctly and the console.log() displays the password. 

Here is my Nodejs code :

```
 app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
     const { name, password } = req.body;

     console.log("FRONT END : ", password);
     console.log("BACK END: ", database[0].password);
     console.log("FRONT END : ", name);
     if(name == database[0].name && password == database[0].password){
         res.json(database[0]);
     }else{
         res.status(400).json("Couldn't get user");
         console.log('didnt work');
     }
 })
```

The console.log() for the name that I post from the front end displays but the console.log() for the password that I post from the front end doesn't. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this was a typo, but in the console log you are using camel case:

```
console.log(this.state.signInPassword);
```

and in the body you missed the I upper case:

```
password: this.state.signinPassword
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did setState({}) on the uppercase one!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
       var data = new FormData();
    data.append("json", JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.signinName,
                password: this.state.signinPassword
            }));    

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: data 
    })
.then(response => response.json())
.then(user => {
    if(user.id){
        this.props.loadUser(user);
        this.props.onRouteChange('home');
    }
})
```

}

Comment: No the problem is not that. I'm getting the username in the terminal of my server but not the password.

Comment: are you getting password on network request of chrome